# dbus: ConnectProfile method: error host is down

Tags: dbus, bluez, gatt

Actually I'm using D-Feet (D-Feet can be used to inspect D-Bus interfaces of running programs and invoke methods on those interfaces) to connect to a BLE peripheral that advertises proximity profile.

When I try the `Connect()` method on the remote object `/org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_6B_0F_00_C4_3A` every thing is fine and the connection succeed but when I try to connect only the proximity profile using `ConnectProfile("0x1802")` method an error occurs saying that the host is down:

> g-io-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Failed: Host is down
>   (36)

Can anyone help me solving this problem (I'm blocked for 2 weeks and there still to much to deal with in the project :/)

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectProfile("0x1802")
```

ConnectProfile (and the Bluez API in general) does not deal with handles, only UUIDs. Your input argument does not look like a UUID: I suggest you find the remote service UUID that matches the handle (I'm assuming your current input argument is a handle).

I believe you can find the UUID with d-feet (after Connect() the service objects should be there) or with bluez command line tools.

Comment: thank you for responding :) but 0x1802 is the 16 bit uuid and even though i tried with the 128 uuid 00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb the same error occur again, i tried also this format 0000180200001000800000805f9b34fb and the same error occur again and again :(